# How can I land on an "IFR-only" airport?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, flight-plans

I was flying Cessna Skyhawk in Microsoft Flight Simulator from Nowy Targ EPNT to Tatry LZTT. I set the weather to cloudy for the purpose of training (a little bit) IFR flight. In general quite big clouds could be spotted around heights of 3000-4000.

When I approached the target airport (and I assume MSFS should have "filed the flight plan" for me if it makes any sense), I asked for permission for landing with full stop, but in response I just got "Tatry airport is IFR only, request denied".

I tried to tune in to Warsaw air control and ask for IFR flight, but I was given order to "Raise to 13000 feet and maintain direction" while I was almost on approach to landing on LZTT.

How would such a situation be handled by the pilot and by ATC in reality? Note that it was well below 3000 and at that level visibility was very good (I mean good enough to do a perfectly safe VFR landing).

Please take into account (that's just informative), that even though I have some knowledge about IFR flying, contacting tower and general procedures, I'm a total amateur flying in the sim and learning about flying for sheer fun. I will be grateful for any explanation, which factors played role in that airport's tower refusing me landing there.

Comment: @Bianfable, a built-in ATC.

Comment: Pause the sim change the clouds and continue VFR.

Comment: @Bianfable, but that's actually what I want to know. How do I implement the proper procedure in the simulator is another story.

Comment: @Spook OK, I tried to rephrase the question to make it clear you're not asking about the sim. But I don't expect the sim ATC to work anything like reality (I haven't flown in MSFS, just my experience with older sim ATCs).

Comment: I don't see this as being answerable as the sim and reality don't match in a way that can be reconciled. Asking how you would go about an IFR flight in reality is very broad, IFR flight is an entire course with more than one book and hours of ground training to go along with it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is clearly a Gamimg question. In the real world ATC will not call an airport IFR and refuse an VFR aircraft to land when conditions are actually VFR.

Comment: @MikeSowsun, What requirements do you need to meet to land on a IFR airport?

Comment: @Spook LZTT is not an IFR airport. Your gaming simulation is wrong to call it IFR when the weather conditions are VFR.

Comment: Not familiar with MSFS, but did you correctly set the flight mode to IFR and define your flight plan when configuring your simulation? The select button under the aircraft type, once you have selected departure/arrival airports?

Comment: As I mention in another comment, LZTT is a restricted use airport that DOES, in fact, requires prior authorization before operating there.  Because flight sims strive for surprising ATC fidelity, the best way to represent this in the sim is to make it an “IFR airport.”  There are many cases of airports having a pre-approved clearance requirement, that are not technically an IFR requirement, but are still beyond “casual VFR” arrivals.

Answer (score 3):

I think your direct question was "how would this be handled in real life?"  There are really three situations:

1. I am already flying on an approved IFR flight plan, and my approach clearance is just a continuation of that IFR flight plan.  The tower already knows I am coming, my aircraft type, and that I and the plane are IFR certified.
2. I need what is in the US called a "pop up" clearance.  I was NOT on an existing IFR flight plan, but ended up encountering unexpected IMC (instrument meteorological conditions).  This could be enroute, or this could happen just at the destination airport.  If both I, and my airplane, are certified *and current* for IFR, I request a pop-up clearance from the controller.  If approved, I will get an IFR clearance to continue.  But as you encountered in the sim, this could require mandatory resequencing and you might be shuffled around into a landing queue.
3. You declare an emergency.  If there is an urgent situation that in your judgment makes landing here, even below VFR minimums, a safety-of-flight issue, you can declare an emergency.  For instance, if weather is settling in all across the region rapidly, so proceeding to any other airport will be more dangerous, you'd declare an emergency.  If you are "urgent fuel" and can't safely make your way to another airport with visual conditions, you'd declare "urgent fuel".  Can't speak for other countries, but they'd (a) help you get down safely and in the US (b) almost certainly give you the phone number of the FSDO, where you'd set an appointment to be interviewed by a safety investigator.  After you landed, they'd say "123L, taxi to parking by taxiway bravo, advise ground when you are able to copy a phone number."

Comment: Those 3 scenarios assume the airport is experiencing IFR weather. The OP has clearly stated the airport was experiencing good VFR weather in this simulation.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Yes, but the OP also clearly stated that the airport was, for whatever reason, not accepting VFR arrivals.  I was not addressing the "why," which in real life would be very unlikely.  I was simply answering that, if an IFR approach is the only means of arrival, then, what could you do?  The options in VMC would be essentially the same--accept the denied clearance and fly elsewhere, pop-up IFR, or declare an emergency.  "Look, it's VMC, so I am landing anyway" probably won't work at a towered airport.  You'll still be copying a phone number for a different kind of call.

Comment: It's an obvious simulator glitch.  If the field is VMC in real life simply cancel IFR.

Comment: @MichaelHall I don’t see this as a simulator “glitch” in the traditional sense.  LZTT is a restricted use airport that requires “prior approval by the Aerodrome Operator” per AIP.  It’s not as simple as proceeding VFR.  Sim logic, which works surprisingly hard to mimic real ATC logic, would have no way to represent this other than designating the airport IFR only.  In the US there are also publicly owned, but restricted operation airports that fall outside our notion of Class B or D.

Comment: @Max, prior permission required (PPR) is separate from an ATC clearance.  In any case, I defer on any peculiarities of airports under the jurisdiction of EASA, and whether or not a flight simulator depicts them accurately.  Would you please elaborate on your last sentence though?

Comment: Anyway, the point of my comment is that the OP's scenario is the direct opposite of the solution in #2.  (Unless you need to be on an IFR clearances for purely administrative reasons)

Comment: @MichaelHall Example:  Military airports are quite often open to civilian/GA operations, but only with prior approval.  If you are a civilian and you have a meeting with an organization at Grand Forks AFB, you will almost vertically be granted an approval letter, where if you show up at the edge of the class D, the answer will almost certainly be no—the exception being declaring an emergency.  This isn’t reflected on sectionals, it just looks like a D on the map.  I *do* appreciate your comments and clarifications, thank you!

Comment: OK, I know that.  "Publicly owned" implied something else...  Either way, a pop-up IFR clearance won't satisfy PPR or "prior approval by the Aerodrome Operator".  #3 is the only real option if you simply must land there.